# AWS Amplify cannot recognize new added file

Tags: aws-amplify

New to Amplify. Following the [tutorial](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/build-serverless-web-app-lambda-apigateway-s3-dynamodb-cognito/) on AWS and everything looks good.

Now I want to add a simple html file, called abc.html, just some basic html code for a test. But when I try to visit the url: https://www.yourdomain.com/abc.html, it redirects the url to https://www.yourdomain.com/abc/. So it basically doesn't recognize there is a file called abc.html. How can I add new files to Amplify?

From Amplify console, everything looks OK. It responded to the `git push`. Provision, build, deploy, verify are all green. It just can't recognize the new added file. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure out the problem. Post it here in case people have the same problem.

It's a bug in Amplify web framework. If you access the file before the branch gets built and deployed, the web framework can't find the file. So it will show 404 page and record the url as 404. Later, even if you build and deploy the file through Amplify, the web framework still remembers the 404 response to the specific url. It won't refresh. That's why if you add a html file to the repo and access it before Amplify finishes deployment, the file is forever treated as not exist.